# How do I create a different 404 page for each site in Liferay 6.1

Tags: glassfish, http-status-code-404, glassfish-3, liferay-6

I am running Liferay 6.1.0 GA1 on Glassfish 3.1.1. I am looking to create a simple 404 error page for my portal site. However, I am unsure of how to do this and cannot find any decent documentation online.

Several forums mention adding a property in the property-ext.properties file

```
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/errors/my_404error.htm
```

However, where does this "my_404error.htm" get stored?

And what if I have several sites on my portal, each styled a different way. How do I create a a customized 404 page for each site?

As I am new to Liferay, I figure there is a simple solution to this problem, I just don't know where to look.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer in a place I should have looked the first time around.

> [The Liferay Developer's Guide](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/official/liferay-developer-guide-6.0.pdf).

Specifically, the section on "Overriding a JSP". That was exactly what I was looking for and I was easily able to tailor it to my Glassfish installation.

Comment: I know it was a year ago, but can you tell if you created a JSP hook to customize the status and error JSPs? the link you posted points to a pdf, can you edit the link to point to the online book's particular section: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development. Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK sure thing. I did create a hook for this. It was pretty simple. Here is the [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-jsp) to the documentation, as requested. You can also check out my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704706/how-do-i-make-liferay-6-1-0-always-redirect-to-a-404-page-when-a-resource-isnt).

Answer (score 0):

Look out in [tomcat_dir]/webapps/ROOT/html, so if you put:

```
$layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/html/errors/404.jsp
```

You have to create that page on that route. Remember to mantain the "html" folder!

Comment: Mister L,Thanks for the response. Any idea how to do this simple task for Glassfish? That's what I'm using. Are these 404 pages even stored in a Liferay Hook as I have been lead to believe, or is this something that needs to be created and maintained outside of Liferay altogether? Thanks

Comment: why maintain the "html" folder? in my root webapp I have a folder "errors" and "html" on the same level.