# How do I make Liferay 6.1.0 always redirect to a 404 page when a resource isn't found?

Tags: redirect, glassfish-3, liferay-6, error-code

I have created a simple hook for a Liferay site I have. It contains a 404.jsp that overrides the default Liferay 404. It works fine if I type in a specific page. For example:

Going to http://localhost:8080/jooky.jsp throws

> SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C%3A%5Cbundles%5Cliferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1%5Cglassfish-3.1.1%5Cdomains%5Cdomain1%5Capplications%5Cliferay-portal%5Cjooky.jsp" not found

in my Glassfish server log and redirects me to my custom /errors/404.jsp without a problem.

However, going to http://localhost:8080/jooky throws a different error

> INFO: 14:07:41,790 INFO  [PortalImpl:4873] Current URL /jooky generates exception: null

and redirects to a page within the portal that looks like this:

[image: Liferay default 404]

Can anyone help me redirect these non-file type URL's to my 404 page as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was still struggling to figure out how to do this until I read the section in the [Liferay Developer's Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development) about "[Overriding a JSP](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4)".
That told me exactly what I needed to know. Where the 404.jsp file should be stored in my hook, why there was a .portal.jsp file appearing in my liferay installation, etc. 
One other critical thing that was *not* mentioned was the addition required to the portal-ext.properties file.
I had to add the following:

```
# 404 page
layout.show.http.status=true
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/errors/404.jsp
```

After a server restart, the 404 page started displaying for all incorrect pages.

Comment: Where `portal-ext.properties` file should be located?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490877/where-does-the-liferay-portal-ext-properties-go