# Redirect Liferay document library missing resource page

Tags: liferay

I have a problem with deleted document library resources that keep appearing on google search results.
When user navigates to search result, liferay shows error page with message "The requested resource was not found". 
Is there any way to redirect user to some 404 page from that error page?
EDIT: Liferay doesn't show any 404 page, it's legitimate document library page with error message "The requested resource was not found".

Comment: Ask google to remove it, or if the website is yours properly handle 404. Speaking about google, can't you find how to handle 404 with liferay on it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704706/how-do-i-make-liferay-6-1-0-always-redirect-to-a-404-page-when-a-resource-isnt

Comment: Look into the `layout.friendly.url.page.not.found` property.

Comment: layout.friendly.url.page.not.found property points to 404.jsp, which is loaded correctly with misspelled urls. But deleted document library resource does not tricker 404, that's the problem. If only there would be a way to make missing resource tricker 404...

Comment: May be you can override the error.jsp with a hook and put in a re-direct script in there.

Comment: I had been looking into something very similar a few months ago and filed an EE support ticket for this very problem which resulted in a feature request. The issue you are experiencing should be addressed with the resolution of [the associated feature ticket](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-52399).